# Hubble Parameter as a function of the scale factor in Lambda CDM Model

Tags: general-relativity

Basically I am trying to plot $H/H_0$ versus $a(t)$ for the Lambda CDM Model. In a paper I am referring to $H/H_0$ decreases with increasing $a(t)$ until a point ($a[t]\sim 0.7$) and then it starts increasing again until today ($a[t]=1$).

When I try doing the same plot using Wikipedia's page on the Lambda CDM Model:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda-CDM_model

(using the expression for $H[a]$ as a function of $a$ in the minimal 6 parameter model); all I get is a decreasing function of time, there is no point where the function $H/H_0$ begins to increase again.

What am I doing wrong? Any help or link to such a graph would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Could you share the reference of the paper you're trying to reproduce?

Comment: Sure. Here is the link to that paper. Refer to figure 1 and only see the Lambda CDM Curve, you can ignore the others: https://arxiv.org/abs/1605.01475

Comment: They are not plotting $H$ they are plotting

$$
\mathcal{H} \equiv a H
$$

which is quite different

Comment: Thanks! I totally missed that. I am gonna try this one and see what I find.

Comment: I was able to reproduce the graph of that paper. But now I am thinking,  should a plot of H(a) versus a not itself have a point where H(a) begins to increase considering the accelerated expansion of the universe? The graph I got initially (not the paper one) was as stated a decreasing function of time.

Answer (score 1):

Below I plot the quantities $H$, $\mathcal{H} = aH$ and $q$

$$
q = -\frac{\ddot{a}a}{\dot{a}^2}
$$

$q$ is known as the [deceleration parameter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deceleration_parameter) and gives you information about the concavity of $a$: the acceleration

[image]

Note that around $z \approx 0.7$ the sign of $q$ changes, meaning that at this redshift the universe starts to accelerate

Comment: Thank you for the quick and detailed responses. It all makes sense. So in accordance with these graphs, should not H(a) versus a in Lambda CDM model have some similar behavior? (i.e., H(a) begins to increase at some a(t) corresponding to z ~0.7). If this is a stupid question you don't have to answer! Thanks again.

Comment: @VishalVerma $H$ increases all the time in $\Lambda$CDM, at what point it changes slope (universe starts accelerating) is a whole different story

Comment: H *decreases* all the time. The time axis is reversed with respect to z.